# Как изменить скрипт модального окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, всплывающее-окно

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать скрипт модального окна. Нужно сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию, т.е. при открытии страницы модальное окно уже было открытым, и при этом кнопка открытия окна была недоступна. Окно закрываем, кнопка открытия появляется. Нажимаем на кнопку, окно открывается, а кнопка становится недоступна. Нужна такая логика. Спасибо большой за помощь!

```js
(function() {
  $(function() {
    // открываем окно
    $('button').click(function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $('.message').addClass('active');
    });
    // закрываем окно
    $('.message').click(function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).add('.okay').click(function() {
      $('.message').removeClass('active');
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

```css
.click {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #260016;
}
.message {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 140px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
  color: button;
  padding: 60px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.message.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.okay {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e68a6c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Открыть</button>
<div class="message">Сообщение
  <button class="okay">Закрыть</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы показать при загрузке, нужно просто сразу же вызвать обработчик показа.
А также, нужно добавить в необходимых местах вызов функции, которая будет скрывать или показывать основную кнопку, например так:

```js
$(function() {
  // закрываем окно
  $('.message').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).add('.okay').click(function() {
    $('.click').show(); // показываем кнопку
    $('.message').removeClass('active');
  });
  // открываем окно
  $('.click').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).hide(); //скрываем кнопку
    $('.message').addClass('active');
  }).click();
});
```

```css
.click {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #260016;
}
.message {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 140px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
  color: button;
  padding: 60px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.message.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.okay {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e68a6c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Открыть</button>
<div class="message">Сообщение
  <button class="okay">Закрыть</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

По сути, надо те действия, которые выполняются для открытия окна по нажатию, выполнить при загрузке страницы. И после открытия окна установить блокирование кнопки добавлением ей атрибута `disabled`:

```js
(function() {
  $(function() {
    // открываем окно при загрузке страницы
    $('.message').addClass('active');
    $('.click').attr('disabled', true);
    // открываем окно по нажатию кнопки
    $('button').click(function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $('.message').addClass('active');
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
    // закрываем окно
    $('.message').click(function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).add('.okay').click(function() {
      $('.message').removeClass('active');
      $('button').attr('disabled', false);
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

```css
.click {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #260016;
  color: #fff;
}
.message {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 140px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
  color: button;
  padding: 60px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.message.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.okay {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e68a6c;
}
button:disabled {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Открыть</button>
<div class="message">Сообщение
  <button class="okay">Закрыть</button>
</div>
```