# Закрытие предыдущего модального окна при открытии нового

Tags: javascript

Имеется 3 модальных окна:

```
          <div id="myModal_1">
            ........
          </div>

          <div id="myModal_2">
            ........
          </div>

          <div id="myModal_3">
            ........
          </div>
```

Как закрыть предыдущее модальное окно при открытии нового?

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: у вас имеется 3 блока и это не модальные окна

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а почему они не могут быть модальными окнами? в чем отличие?

Comment: @Air  отличие в том что модальные окна имеют режим который регулируется в js , в этом случае даже даже css нету, а подобные всплывашки так же легко делаются на css3

Comment: Они на бутстрапе, чтобы кучу кода не писать я в виде дивов с id описал. Из-за слабого знания js не знаю как это на нем описать.

Comment: @Air  в каком месте я рассмешил ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ну в том, что почти любой элемент может быть модальным окном.. Просто его надо соответствующи  оформить...  Модальное окно это состояние... Ну или как ты выразился режим...  Просто автор решил не напрягать себя стилями, а c JS может вообще не знаком и решил просто получить готовый script

Comment: Ну в принципе я хотел чтобы описали как правильно на малом примере, чтобы я понял. Я логику прекрасно понимаю, но не знаю как это правильно описать на js. Может подскажете?

Comment: @Air а есть ли у вас предложение как помочь человеку вместо колких замечаний? predel2007 - попробуйте почитать про модальные окна bootstrap тут http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/v4-alpha/components/modal/. там есть примеры JS для событий (т.е. как они открываются). Ваша задача - создать последовательность, где кнопка закрытия 1ого окна (close) будет кнопокой вызова 2-ого окна и так далее.

Comment: @alexoander, подобные вопросы надо закрывать а не отвечать на них...

Comment: @Air Тогда попросили бы дополнить вопрос, чтобы на него ответить. А не устраивать дискуссию по поводу того, что вам не нравится. С уважением, но ваша позиция не является правильной.

Comment: predel2007 - дополните свой вопрос деталями.Например, опишите ваши попытки сделать вызов для показа хотябы одного окна на JS.  А лучше если вы сможете сделать минимально воспроизводимый пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Вот вам для примера вот такой вариант [ТЫК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541252/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0?rq=1)

Comment: @alexoander, может стоит автору обратить внимание на первый комментарий? Не ответа не привета...

Comment: вот пример одного из модальных окон:

Comment: #button_rufuse - это id кнопки которая открывает новое модальное окно (средствами бутстрапа), #myModal_delete_order - это id предыдущего модального окна. По клику на него новое откроется бутстрапом, а чтобы закрыть предыдущее я пробовал так: $(document).ready(function(){
$('#button_rufuse').click(function(){
    $('#myModal_delete_order').modal('hide');
  }); - но ничего не получается и ругается на синтаксис

Comment: Спорщики)) Можно так-то обратить внимание на то что в HTML _вообще нет_ модальных окон (кроме браузерных confirm и prompt)... Это популярная ошибка в терминологии, которую люди бездумно повторяют и передают новичкам.

Answer (score 3):

Ни в коем случае не претендую на золотую медаль

на css3

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modal {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: none;
}

.modal:target {
  display: block;
}

.modal a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="m1" class="modal">первое окно <a href="#">x</a></div>
<div id="m2" class="modal">второе окно <a href="#">x</a></div>
<div id="m3" class="modal">третье окно <a href="#">x</a></div>

<a href="#m1">открыть окно1</a>
<a href="#m2">открыть окно2</a>
<a href="#m3">открыть окно3</a>
```

на jQuery

```js
$(".a1").on("click", function() {
  $("#m1").show();
  $(".outer").show();
});
$(".a2").on("click", function() {
  $("#m2").show();
  $(".outer").show();
});
$(".a3").on("click", function() {
  $("#m3").show();
  $(".outer").show();
});

$(".outer").click(function() {
  $(".modal").hide();
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modal {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: none;
  z-index: 11;
}

.modal a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="m1" class="modal">окно 1</div>
<div id="m2" class="modal">окно 2</div>
<div id="m3" class="modal">окно 3</div>

<button class="a1">открыть окно 1</button>
<button class="a2">открыть окно 2</button>
<button class="a3">открыть окно 3</button>


<div class="outer"></div>
```